# Flex 3: HBox children Scrolling with buttons

Tags: apache-flex

I have an HBox with width=500.
I actually want to add two arrows buttons that will scroll the contents of the HBox.
But when I turn HBox's scroll policy to off, I can't scroll it programmatically using `horizontalScrollPosition`.

What should i do now?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hacked together this custom HBox that you could use. Simply set `horizontalScrollPolicy` to either "on" or "auto". I really haven't tested it all that much, works for a simple test I did...

```
public class CustomHBox extends HBox
{
    override public function validateDisplayList():void
    {
        super.validateDisplayList();

        if (horizontalScrollBar)
            horizontalScrollBar.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bars will not be displayed when [scrollPolicy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#verticalScrollPolicy) is turned off.

Comment: I know, But when i turn then off, I cant scroll the contents of the HBOX programmatically. How can i scroll the contents while scrollPolicy is off?

Comment: what happens when you set the scrollpolicy? is there any content to be scrolled? `trace(hbox.maxHorizontalScrollPosition)` to see if there is anything to be scrolled at all

Comment: i get 0, flex disables this attribute after turning off horizontal scroll policy

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you want, you want to subclass ScrollBar make it look and feel the way you would like, then set it on your [Container.horizontalScrollBar](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#horizontalScrollBar)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Flex expert, but this is possible without too much trouble (using Flex SDK 3.2, anyway). You're right - when you turn off the `horizontalScrollPolicy`, the `maxHorizontalScollPosition` is set to 0, UNLESS you specify both a `width` value AND a `maxWidth` value. Then, `maxHorizontalScrollPosition` will again contain a useable value, and you'll be able to programmatically set the `horizontalScrollPosition`.